textfield editing with stream builder refreshing the screen automatically
  final OrderEntity orderEntity;
  Map<String, List<OrderItem>> itemsGroupedByUser;
  late Future<Map<String, RegisterAccountModel>> userMapFuture;
  final Future<void>? addItem;
  bool isCreator = false;
  bool isCurrentUserPlacerOrReceiver;
  final VoidCallback? onCalculatePressed;
  final dynamic updateOrderStatus;
  final dynamic assignUsersAndNotify;
  final String itemName;
  final Function(String) setItemName;
  final int itemCount;
  final Function(int) setItemCount;
  final TextEditingController itemController;

  OrderDetailsBody(
      {super.key,
      required this.orderEntity,
      required this.itemsGroupedByUser,
      required this.userMapFuture,
      this.addItem,
      required this.isCreator,
      required this.isCurrentUserPlacerOrReceiver,
      this.onCalculatePressed,
      this.updateOrderStatus,
      required this.itemName,
      required this.setItemName,
      required this.itemCount,
      required this.setItemCount,
      required this.itemController,
      this.assignUsersAndNotify});

  @override
  State<OrderDetailsBody> createState() => _OrderDetailsBodyState();
}

class _OrderDetailsBodyState extends State<OrderDetailsBody> {
  late GetUserUsecase getUserOrderUsecase;
  late AddOrderUsecase addOrderUsecase;
  late String createdAt;
  User? currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  Future<void> addItem(String itemName, int itemCount) async {
    if (itemName.isNotEmpty && itemCount > 0) {
      OrderItem orderItem = OrderItem(
        itemName: itemName,
        quantity: itemCount,
        userId: currentUser!.uid,
      );
      widget.orderEntity.items?.add(orderItem);
      setState(() {
        widget.orderEntity.items?.add(orderItem);
        // Clear the text field and reset itemCount
        widget.setItemName('');
        widget.setItemCount(0);
      });
      addOrderUsecase.update(widget.orderEntity);
      //
      //setState(() {
      //   // itemsList.add(orderItem);
      //   itemController.clear();
      //   itemCount = 0;
      //   _handleItemAdded();
      //   // updateOrdersAndUsers();
      // });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    addOrderUsecase = sl();
    getUserOrderUsecase = sl();
    createdAt = widget.orderEntity.createdAt != null
        ? DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a').format(widget.orderEntity.createdAt)
        : 'Unknown';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const divider = Divider(
      thickness: 1,
      height: 3,
    );
    return FutureBuilder<Map<String, RegisterAccountModel>>(
        future: widget.userMapFuture,
        builder: (context, userSnapshot) {
          if (userSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: LoadingWidget());
          }

          if (userSnapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Error: ${userSnapshot.error}'));
          }

          if (!userSnapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: Text('Users not found.'));
          }
          String itemName = '';
          int itemCount = 0;
          double keyboardHeight = 0;

          Map<String, RegisterAccountModel> userMap = userSnapshot.data!;
          return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Created At : $createdAt",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.separated(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: widget.itemsGroupedByUser.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    String userId =
                        widget.itemsGroupedByUser.keys.elementAt(index);
                    List<OrderItem> userItems =
                        widget.itemsGroupedByUser[userId]!;
                    return EventDetailPageItemTile(
                      userId: userId,
                      orderEntity: widget.orderEntity,
                      items: userItems,
                      user: userMap[userId],
                      status: widget.orderEntity.status,
                      // onDeleteItem: (item) => _deleteItem(item),
                    );
                  },
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => divider,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Visibility(
                    // visible: orderEntity.status == OrderStatusEnum.active,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: widget.itemController,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Add Item',
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            ),
                            onChanged: widget.setItemName,
                          ),

                          // onTap: () {
                          //   // setState(() {
                          //   // keyboardHeight = 300;
                          //   // });
                          // },
                          // onTapOutside: (value) {
                          //   // setState(() {
                          //   // keyboardHeight = 0;
                          //   // FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                          //   // });
                          // },
                          // onEditingComplete: () {
                          //   // setState(() {
                          //   // keyboardHeight = 0;
                          //   // FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                          //   // });
                          // },
                          // onChanged: (value) {
                          //   itemName = value;
                          // },
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 10),
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            // setState(() {
                            widget.setItemCount(widget.itemCount > 0
                                ? widget.itemCount - 1
                                : 0); // });
                          },
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '${widget.itemCount}',
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            // setState(() {
                            widget.setItemCount(widget.itemCount + 1); // });
                          },
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 10),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 100,
                          child: CommonElevatedButtonWidget(
                            text: 'Add',
                            onPressed: () =>
                                addItem(widget.itemName, widget.itemCount),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Visibility(
                      visible:
                          widget.orderEntity.status == OrderStatusEnum.active &&
                              (widget.isCreator ||
                                  widget.isCurrentUserPlacerOrReceiver),
                      child: CommonElevatedButtonWidget(
                        text: 'Place Your Order...',
                        width: 100.w,
                        onPressed: () async {
                          setState(() {
                            for (var userId in widget.itemsGroupedByUser.keys) {
                              PushNotificationService.sendNotificationToUser(
                                userId,
                                "The Order You're Joined Is Placed Successfully",
                              );
                              NotificationService.saveNotification(
                                  "The Order You're Joined Is Placed Successfully",
                                  "We Will Wait it together",
                                  userId);
                            }
                            widget.orderEntity.status = OrderStatusEnum.arrived;
                            widget.updateOrderStatus();
                          });
                          widget.orderEntity.status = OrderStatusEnum.placed;
                          widget.updateOrderStatus();
                          await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
                          await widget.assignUsersAndNotify(userMap);
                          await Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => ViewOrderPage(
                                onCalculate: widget.onCalculatePressed,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // SizedBox(
                  //   height: keyboardHeight,
                  // ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
class OrderDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  late OrderEntity orderEntity;

  OrderDetailsPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.orderEntity,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OrderDetailsPage> createState() => _OrderDetailsPageState();
}

class _OrderDetailsPageState extends State<OrderDetailsPage> {
  late GetUserUsecase getUserOrderUsecase;
  late AddOrderUsecase addOrderUsecase;
  late String createdAt;
  User? currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  RegisterAccountModel? placer;
  RegisterAccountModel? receiver;
  bool isCreator = false;
  late Future<Map<String, RegisterAccountModel>> userMapFuture;
  late Stream<OrderEntity> _orderStream;
  String itemName = '';
  int itemCount = 0;
  final TextEditingController _itemController = TextEditingController();

  void onCalculatePressed() {
    refreshOrder();
  }

  void setItemName(String value) {
    setState(() {
      itemName = value;
    });
  }

  void setItemCount(int value) {
    setState(() {
      itemCount = value;
    });
  }

  Future<Map<String, RegisterAccountModel>> loadUsers(
      List<String> userIds) async {
    return await getUserOrderUsecase.getUsers(userIds);
  }

  Map<String, List<OrderItem>> getItemsGroupedByUsers(
      List<OrderItem> itemsList) {
    Map<String, List<OrderItem>> itemsGroupedByUser = {};
    for (var item in itemsList) {
      itemsGroupedByUser.putIfAbsent(item.userId, () => []).add(item);
    }
    return itemsGroupedByUser;
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    addOrderUsecase = sl();
    getUserOrderUsecase = sl();
    createdAt = widget.orderEntity.createdAt != null
        ? DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a').format(widget.orderEntity.createdAt)
        : 'Unknown';
    isCreator = currentUser?.uid == widget.orderEntity.userId;
    _orderStream = OrderCubit().getOrderStream(widget.orderEntity.id);
  }

  refreshOrder() async {
    widget.orderEntity =
        await addOrderUsecase.remoteGetOrder(widget.orderEntity.id);
    // updateOrdersAndUsers();
  }

  dynamic updateOrderStatus() {
    addOrderUsecase.updateOrderStatus(
        widget.orderEntity.id, widget.orderEntity.status);
  }

  Future<void> assignUsersAndNotify(
      Map<String, RegisterAccountModel> userMap) async {
    List<RegisterAccountModel> usersInOrder = userMap.values.toList();
    usersInOrder
        .sort((a, b) => a.placedOrderCount!.compareTo(b.placedOrderCount!));

    placer = null;
    receiver = null;

    for (var user in usersInOrder) {
      if (placer == null &&
          (user.deliveryPreference == "Place the order" ||
              user.hasCar == "No")) {
        placer = user;
        widget.orderEntity.placerUid = placer!.userId;
      }
      if (placer != null) {
        break;
      }
    }

    if (placer == null && usersInOrder.isNotEmpty) {
      placer = usersInOrder.first;
      widget.orderEntity.placerUid = placer!.userId;
    }

    for (var user in usersInOrder) {
      if (receiver == null &&
          (user.hasCar == "Yes" ||
              user.deliveryPreference == "Receive it at the gate")) {
        receiver = user;
        widget.orderEntity.receiverUid = receiver!.userId;
      }
      if (receiver != null) {
        break;
      }
    }

    if (receiver == null && usersInOrder.isNotEmpty) {
      usersInOrder.sort(
          (a, b) => a.receivedOrderCount!.compareTo(b.receivedOrderCount!));
      receiver = usersInOrder.firstWhere(
          (user) => user.userId != placer?.userId,
          orElse: () => usersInOrder.first);
      if (receiver != null) {
        widget.orderEntity.receiverUid = receiver!.userId;
      }
    }
    if (placer != null) {
      await placer!.incrementPlacedOrderCount();
      await _firestore
          .collection('Users')
          .doc(placer!.userId)
          .update(placer!.toMap());
      PushNotificationService.sendNotificationToUser(placer!.userId,
          "You're Chosen To Place The Order, Thank You So Much For Your Help");
      NotificationService.saveNotification("You're Chosen To Place The Order",
          "Thank You So Much For Your Help", placer!.userId);
    }

    if (receiver != null) {
      await receiver!.incrementReceivedOrderCount();
      await _firestore
          .collection('Users')
          .doc(receiver!.userId)
          .update(receiver!.toMap());
      PushNotificationService.sendNotificationToUser(receiver!.userId,
          "You're Chosen To Receive The Order At The Gate, Thank You So Much For Your Help");
      NotificationService.saveNotification(
          "You're Chosen To Receive The Order At The Gate",
          "Thank You So Much For Your Help",
          receiver!.userId);
    }

    await addOrderUsecase.update(widget.orderEntity);

    await _firestore.collection('Order').doc(widget.orderEntity.id).update({
      'placerUid': placer?.userId,
      'receiverUid': receiver?.userId,
    });

    setState(() {});
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isCurrentUserPlacerOrReceiver = currentUser != null &&
        (currentUser!.uid == placer?.userId ||
            currentUser!.uid == receiver?.userId);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBarWidget(
        pageName: widget.orderEntity.title ?? '',
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<OrderEntity>(
        stream: _orderStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: LoadingWidget());
          }

          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
          }

          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: Text('Order not found.'));
          }

          OrderEntity orderEntity = snapshot.data!;
          List<OrderItem> itemsList = snapshot.data!.items ?? [];
          Map<String, List<OrderItem>> itemsGroupedByUser =
              getItemsGroupedByUsers(itemsList);
          userMapFuture = loadUsers(itemsGroupedByUser.keys.toList());

          return OrderDetailsBody(
            orderEntity: widget.orderEntity,
            itemsGroupedByUser: itemsGroupedByUser,
            userMapFuture: userMapFuture,
            isCreator: isCreator,
            isCurrentUserPlacerOrReceiver: isCurrentUserPlacerOrReceiver,
            onCalculatePressed: onCalculatePressed,
            assignUsersAndNotify: assignUsersAndNotify,
            updateOrderStatus: updateOrderStatus(),
            itemName: itemName,
            setItemName: setItemName,
            itemCount: itemCount,
            setItemCount: setItemCount,
            itemController: _itemController,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
 `

`class OrderDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  late OrderEntity orderEntity;

  OrderDetailsPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.orderEntity,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OrderDetailsPage> createState() => _OrderDetailsPageState();
}

class _OrderDetailsPageState extends State<OrderDetailsPage> {
  late GetUserUsecase getUserOrderUsecase;
  late AddOrderUsecase addOrderUsecase;
  late String createdAt;
  User? currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  RegisterAccountModel? placer;
  RegisterAccountModel? receiver;
  bool isCreator = false;
  late Future<Map<String, RegisterAccountModel>> userMapFuture;
  late Stream<OrderEntity> _orderStream;
  String itemName = '';
  int itemCount = 0;
  final TextEditingController _itemController = TextEditingController();

  void onCalculatePressed() {
    refreshOrder();
  }

  void setItemName(String value) {
    setState(() {
      itemName = value;
    });
  }

  void setItemCount(int value) {
    setState(() {
      itemCount = value;
    });
  }

  Future<Map<String, RegisterAccountModel>> loadUsers(
      List<String> userIds) async {
    return await getUserOrderUsecase.getUsers(userIds);
  }

  Map<String, List<OrderItem>> getItemsGroupedByUsers(
      List<OrderItem> itemsList) {
    Map<String, List<OrderItem>> itemsGroupedByUser = {};
    for (var item in itemsList) {
      itemsGroupedByUser.putIfAbsent(item.userId, () => []).add(item);
    }
    return itemsGroupedByUser;
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    addOrderUsecase = sl();
    getUserOrderUsecase = sl();
    createdAt = widget.orderEntity.createdAt != null
        ? DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a').format(widget.orderEntity.createdAt)
        : 'Unknown';
    isCreator = currentUser?.uid == widget.orderEntity.userId;
    _orderStream = OrderCubit().getOrderStream(widget.orderEntity.id);
  }

  refreshOrder() async {
    widget.orderEntity =
        await addOrderUsecase.remoteGetOrder(widget.orderEntity.id);
    // updateOrdersAndUsers();
  }

  dynamic updateOrderStatus() {
    addOrderUsecase.updateOrderStatus(
        widget.orderEntity.id, widget.orderEntity.status);
  }

  Future<void> assignUsersAndNotify(
      Map<String, RegisterAccountModel> userMap) async {
    List<RegisterAccountModel> usersInOrder = userMap.values.toList();
    usersInOrder
        .sort((a, b) => a.placedOrderCount!.compareTo(b.placedOrderCount!));

    placer = null;
    receiver = null;

    for (var user in usersInOrder) {
      if (placer == null &&
          (user.deliveryPreference == "Place the order" ||
              user.hasCar == "No")) {
        placer = user;
        widget.orderEntity.placerUid = placer!.userId;
      }
      if (placer != null) {
        break;
      }
    }

    if (placer == null && usersInOrder.isNotEmpty) {
      placer = usersInOrder.first;
      widget.orderEntity.placerUid = placer!.userId;
    }

    for (var user in usersInOrder) {
      if (receiver == null &&
          (user.hasCar == "Yes" ||
              user.deliveryPreference == "Receive it at the gate")) {
        receiver = user;
        widget.orderEntity.receiverUid = receiver!.userId;
      }
      if (receiver != null) {
        break;
      }
    }

    if (receiver == null && usersInOrder.isNotEmpty) {
      usersInOrder.sort(
          (a, b) => a.receivedOrderCount!.compareTo(b.receivedOrderCount!));
      receiver = usersInOrder.firstWhere(
          (user) => user.userId != placer?.userId,
          orElse: () => usersInOrder.first);
      if (receiver != null) {
        widget.orderEntity.receiverUid = receiver!.userId;
      }
    }
    if (placer != null) {
      await placer!.incrementPlacedOrderCount();
      await _firestore
          .collection('Users')
          .doc(placer!.userId)
          .update(placer!.toMap());
      PushNotificationService.sendNotificationToUser(placer!.userId,
          "You're Chosen To Place The Order, Thank You So Much For Your Help");
      NotificationService.saveNotification("You're Chosen To Place The Order",
          "Thank You So Much For Your Help", placer!.userId);
    }

    if (receiver != null) {
      await receiver!.incrementReceivedOrderCount();
      await _firestore
          .collection('Users')
          .doc(receiver!.userId)
          .update(receiver!.toMap());
      PushNotificationService.sendNotificationToUser(receiver!.userId,
          "You're Chosen To Receive The Order At The Gate, Thank You So Much For Your Help");
      NotificationService.saveNotification(
          "You're Chosen To Receive The Order At The Gate",
          "Thank You So Much For Your Help",
          receiver!.userId);
    }

    await addOrderUsecase.update(widget.orderEntity);

    await _firestore.collection('Order').doc(widget.orderEntity.id).update({
      'placerUid': placer?.userId,
      'receiverUid': receiver?.userId,
    });

    setState(() {});
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isCurrentUserPlacerOrReceiver = currentUser != null &&
        (currentUser!.uid == placer?.userId ||
            currentUser!.uid == receiver?.userId);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBarWidget(
        pageName: widget.orderEntity.title ?? '',
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<OrderEntity>(
        stream: _orderStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: LoadingWidget());
          }

          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
          }

          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: Text('Order not found.'));
          }

          OrderEntity orderEntity = snapshot.data!;
          List<OrderItem> itemsList = snapshot.data!.items ?? [];
          Map<String, List<OrderItem>> itemsGroupedByUser =
              getItemsGroupedByUsers(itemsList);
          userMapFuture = loadUsers(itemsGroupedByUser.keys.toList());

          return OrderDetailsBody(
            orderEntity: widget.orderEntity,
            itemsGroupedByUser: itemsGroupedByUser,
            userMapFuture: userMapFuture,
            isCreator: isCreator,
            isCurrentUserPlacerOrReceiver: isCurrentUserPlacerOrReceiver,
            onCalculatePressed: onCalculatePressed,
            assignUsersAndNotify: assignUsersAndNotify,
            updateOrderStatus: updateOrderStatus(),
            itemName: itemName,
            setItemName: setItemName,
            itemCount: itemCount,
            setItemCount: setItemCount,
            itemController: _itemController,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

when i typing in the text field for adding item in the order details body the screen refreshing automatically and i use stream builder and future builder because i need to get the orders from collection and the users from another collection and it didnt work well when i press on textfield of adding items the screen refreshing and the future builder rebuild again
